# Ender 3v2 mid print extrusion issue

Tags: extruder, bed-leveling, extrusion, nozzle, underextrusion

I have been using my 3D printer for 3 years and it has been working very well for the past 6 months. I had never calibrated the bed even once in these 6 months because it was flat and had never been messed up. BLTouch has been working really well.

Two weeks ago, I printed a very long print for the first time, about 48 hours long, and there were more to come. After that print, the bed calibration keeps getting messed up constantly, and even though I get a smooth first layer print, as I go up to the upper layers, it turns out like the picture shown.

I have changed the nozzle many times, replaced the Teflon tube, and pushed it firmly into place. I also updated the bed springs, but it didn't fix the issue at all. I am using eSun PLA+ white. The 3D printer is an Ender 3v2 BLTouch updated. I would appreciate it if you could help me with this issue.

Nozzle temp: 200 °C-210 °C

Bed temp: 60 °C

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Please add some image descriptions so that we know what we are looking at.